# Automatically add hyphens to number field

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

My form has a few fields that need filters.  For instance, there is a SSN field.

I am currently checking that the user has entered in the correct pattern (and displaying validation that it is wrong if need be).  However, this requires the user to enter the hyphens themselves.  What I would like to do is automatically adds the hyphens as the user enters their number.

How would I accomplish something like this?  I already have a custom type that I created for the SSN field.  Maybe in the controller of this custom field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just realized that Kent already has an example of how to do this using [uiMask](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask) module:

http://angular-formly.com/#!/example/integrations/ui-mask

Answer (score 4):

I have used the [angular-ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/) library's `ui-mask` for this.

An input mask of `999-99-9999` is what you are describing.  A demo of the `ui-mask` directive can be found [here](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask/master/demo/index.html).

Comment: Thanks David, while this answer is correct...the answer that I just posted actually describes how to apply `ui-mask` to AngularFormly.

Comment: No worries. I've actually not encountered angular-formly yet and am checking it out now!

Comment: I have been using it for a few weeks now.  It is a very different way to create forms.  Once you get the hang of it though, it is a powerful way to create forms.